# How to repair damaged AAC file without re-encoding using FFmpeg or other tools?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a 256Kbps AAC file that has a corrupted segment lasting less ~1/20th of a second. I'm seeking to "repair" the damaged portion without re-encoding - or, at least via a minimally invasive procedure.

Audacity: corrupt segment/"glitch":
[image: Audacity: corrupt segment/"glitch"]

The corrupt portion is during a period of a few seconds where the only sound is a continuous, single synth musical note, accompanied by some light audience applause in the background, and as such, I am able, using creative editing, to repair the corrupt portion in Audacity, as follows, but the file must be converted to lossless to do so:

1. Trim out corrupt portion (2290 samples)
2. Merge/crossfade the preceding and subsequent portions of the track on either side of the deleted, corrupt portion with an overlap of 2120 samples
3. This results in an overall shortening of the track by 4410 samples (1/10th second)
4. The newly edited file plays back with continuous tone/sound, and the glitch is not detectable
5. In order to retain track duration, I then cut a 4410 sample portion from the vicinity of the recent repair, then duplicate it by splicing it into the region of said repair
6. Final result: original track duration retained, glitch is virtually undetected upon playback.

That said, I can only achieve this result when I edit in lossless in Audacity, and I would like to achieve a similar result in the lossy file without re-encoding. I've attempted to simply cut out the corrupt portion of the original file, and then replace it with a re-encoded repaired portion from the repair file. However, I am running up against the inability to cut out a repair portion and match it exactly within the segment of the original file due to timestamp offsets.

I'm hoping there's a way to work through this.  Is there a way to remove or alter timestamps such that I can then cut/edit my lossy files at the sample level?  Until now, using ffmpeg, if I split files at a timestamp, it splits at the nearest timestamp, which could be ~100+ samples adjacent to where I need to effect an edit.

Open to any other ideas, as well.

Comment: You can't. AAC encoding uses overlapping windows i.e. the encoding of samples at time range C to E depend upon coding of samples at time range B to D.

Answer (score 0):

Audacity and most audio editors decompresses the audio when you load
the file, and when re-exporting it in a lossy format you are now doing
another round of lossy compression, although
MP4 (AAC) was designed to minimize the damage from multiple encodes,
so you should not be losing much quality.

An alternative product is
[mp3DirectCut](https://mp3directcut.en.softonic.com/):

> **Cut and edit MP3 and AAC fast and easily**
>
> mp3DirectCut is a fast and extensive audio editor for encoded MP3 and
> AAC. Without re-encoding directly cut, crop, split and join your
> tracks, create fades on MP3 and much more. Direct lossless editing
> saves encoding time and preserves the audio quality of encoded tracks.
> The built in recorder creates MP3 on the fly. With Cue sheets, Pause
> detection or Auto cue you can easily divide long files.